# How to signup user via phone number using firebase in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a **login and sign up** system using firebase in my **flutter** app.

Primary login will be based on the **Phone number**.

-For signup I intend to require:

- **Phoone number**(required)
- Name
- State and city

*On, submit I will send an OTP to the phone number to verify and successfully create a profile of the user.*

-For login I will require that phone number, the OTP to phone number will be send and then successfully login.

I have seen the email and password-based login and signup with the following:

- `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`
- `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`

-Currently, I have found `verifyPhoneNumber()` But, don't know how signup will be done. Also, how will it verify when signup hasn't happened?

Please direct me accordingly.

Edit:
I am not using Firestore to store any data. For that, I have the backend to receive data using auth token sent in the header.

Answer (score 2):

You can first enable phone number authentication from firebase console.
After you do that, suppose you have have a phone number collected from a form. Below code can achieve auth for android. For iOS, please see docs.

```dart
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
  phoneNumber: '+91 999 999 999',
  verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
    
    await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  },
);
```

Later, you can create a firebase collection that will contain Name, state, and city after you request it from user through another form. There is nothing like signup here, the authentication is phone number based, if user is new you have request these details, else it is a sign in.

Comment: Sings up new user as well

Answer (score 0):

try `firebase_auth 0.15.3`

```
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

demo

```
void _verifyPhoneNumber() async {

    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
        (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
      _auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
      setState(() {
        _message = 'Received phone auth credential: $phoneAuthCredential';
      });
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
        (AuthException authException) {
      setState(() {
        _message =
            'Phone number verification failed. Code: ${authException.code}. Message: ${authException.message}';
      });
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
        (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
      widget._scaffold.showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
        content: Text('Please check your phone for the verification code.'),
      ));
      _verificationId = verificationId;
    };

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
        (String verificationId) {
      _verificationId = verificationId;
    };

    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: //put here phone number,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
  }
```

hope it helps

Comment: from my understanding, the above just verify the user's but i dont think it log's inthe user because it was already created .. please correct if wrong